# Enabling git log parameters by default

Tags: alias, git-log, git-config

I like the way that the following command prints out git logs:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

I would like to make that the default format whenever I use git log.  Is there a way to edit `~/.gitconfig` to enable oneline, decorate, and graph by default?

And yes, I'm aware that I can alias those options to another git command alias, but I'd rather that log just print out using those options by default.

Answer (score 7):

Git allows you to activate `--oneline` and `--decorate` by default for `log`, `show`, etc.:

```
git config --global format.pretty oneline
git config --global log.decorate short
```

However, as of <del>v2.1.0</del> v2.2.2, Git does not allow you to activate `--graph` by default. One way around that (adapted from [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/105389/216162)) is to define the following function in your `.<shell>rc` file:

```sh
git() {
    if [ "$1" = "log" ]
    then
        command git log --graph "${@:2}";
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

**One caveat** (pointed out by `hvd` in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701695/enabling-git-log-parameters-by-default/25712489#comment40193829_25712489)): if you specify options between `git` and `log`, as in

```sh
git -c log.showroot=false log -p
```

then, because the first argument is `-c` and not `log`, the `--oneline --decorate --graph` flags won't be used.

Comment: Looks good (and nicely spotted that `log` shouldn't be repeated, and would be with my suggestion), although there's still a small risk with `git -c log.showroot=false log -p`: `log` is not the first argument here.

Comment: Perhaps stick to just `--graph` in the shell function and the rest in git config? `--graph` is the only one that cannot be defined in the git config and we should use always try to use the built-in tool where possible. Otherwise you override the `format.pretty` and `log.decorate` configs globally when it might be repository-specific.

Comment: Also consider shortening the commit hash using [the `log.abbrevCommit` configuration option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-logabbrevCommit).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `git config --global format.pretty oneline` which displays the full commit hash is to define your own format.

The following will:

1. Keep color sheme
2. Use abbreviated commit hash
3. allow for decoration (branch name)
4. add commit titles

```
git config --global format.pretty "%C(auto)%h %d %s"
```

For comparison:

`git config --global format.pretty oneline` Output:

```
59264eb68e610ef8edb99c364be9f2164d80ca14 (HEAD -> migration-service, origin/master, master) Merged PR 13: #52 Implement My library
f970b40b588cc9aae48f0e0953a538872f742843 Initial Commit
```

`git config --global format.pretty "%C(auto)%h %d %s"` Output:

```
59264eb  (HEAD -> migration-service, origin/master, master) Merged PR 13: #52 Implement My library
f970b40  Initial Commit
```

For more about format strings see Git docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats